# C# Linq to group by object properties

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Email;
    public int Value1;     
    public datetime Value2;
    //etc
}

public class MyItems : List<MyItem> {}
```

I populate a MyItems object with a list of random items. Now I need to break this list into smaller lists, whereby each list contains only the items that have the same 'Email' property.

Can this be achieved using Linq?

Comment: Why do you inherit a class from `List<T>` ?

Comment: No particular reason. I might add specific methods to that class though.

Comment: Yes, it can absolutely be achieved in LINQ, using `GroupBy` (or the equivalent query expression). Now, what have you tried and what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `List<MyItem>` you can simply use `GroupBy`:

```
myItems.GroupBy(x => x.Email).Select(g => g.ToList());
```

This will return a `IEnumerable<List<MyItem>>`

Or you can use `ToDictionary` and you can access your groups by `Email`:

```
myItems.GroupBy(x => x.Email).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
MyItems myItems = new MyItems();

//Populate here

myItems.GroupBy(x => x.Email).Select(group => group.ToList());
```

Here you get a collection of lists that you can use

Comment: How would this look like using Linq?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: You may be confusing the two different ways of expressing linq. The `from x in myItems Select blah` type syntax is just sugar that get converted to method syntax by the compiler before execution.